# Error C2280 vector of objects that have unique_ptr members

Tags: c++, vector, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I believe I know *why* this is happening, but being new to c++ I'm unsure what the *correct* way to handle it is (without using raw pointers). From my research what is happening is that when I attempt to `push_back` a `Stage` object into a vector a copy is being attempted and since `Stage` contains `unique_ptr` members which have deleted copy constructors, the below error is encountered.

Is my understanding correct? If so, what is the best way to resolve this issue in modern c++?

**Minimal Reproducible Example**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Actor
{
private:
    int prop1 = 1;
    int prop2 = 2;
public:
    Actor() {}
};

class Stage
{
public:
    Stage() {}
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Actor>> actors;
};

class App
{
public:
    App() {}
    std::vector<Stage> stages;
};

int main()
{
    auto act1 = std::make_unique<Actor>();

    auto sta1 = Stage();
    sta1.actors.push_back(std::move(act1));

    auto app = App();
    app.stages.push_back(sta1); // Issue occurs when copying Stage object into vector since Stage object contains members of type unique_ptr (or at least that's my best guess from the research I have done)

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

**Compiler Error from MSVC**

```
Error   C2280   'std::unique_ptr<Actor,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(
const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)': attempting to 
reference a deleted function    SmartPointers   
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\xmemory0    945
```

Comment: `app.stages.push_back(std::move(sta1));` ? Copy constructor for `Stage` is implicitly deleted, but move constructor should be available.

Comment: Use `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unique_ptr` cannot be copied, only moved. That's why it's called unique in the first place.

You used the right approach when pushing to `actors` so you only need to adapt it to `stages`.

```
 app.stages.push_back(std::move(sta1));
```